# how to fix this command menu

Tags: bash, unix

This menu shell script allows me to execute commands, yet theres an issue; once i input the choice the command runs and the menu shows up right after the result without clearing the screen.

```
#!/bin/sh
LOGO="t13 Menu"
amenu="a.  db"                 ;
bmenu="b.  listening ports "           ; 
cmenu="c.  Display Directory Listing " ; 
dmenu="d.  MenuCID "                   ;


badchoice () { MSG="Invalid Selection ... Please Try Again" ; } 

apick () { ps -rf | grep pemon ;}
bpick () { lsof -n | grep LISTEN ; }
cpick () { ls -ltr | more ; }
dpick () { menujob ; }

clear

themenu () {


echo `date`
echo
echo "\t\t\t" $LOGO
echo
echo "\t\tPlease Select:"
echo
echo "\t\t\t" $amenu
echo "\t\t\t" $bmenu
echo "\t\t\t" $cmenu
echo "\t\t\t" $dmenu
echo
echo
echo "\t\t\t\tx. Exit"
echo
echo $MSG
echo
echo Select by pressing the letter and then ENTER ;
}

MSG=

while  true
do
  themenu
  read answer
  MSG=

  case $answer in
      a|A) apick;;
      b|B) bpick;;
      c|C) cpick;;
      d|D) dpick;;
      e|E) epick;;

      x|X) break;;
      *) badchoice;;

   esac

done
```

what i expect is :
after the input of choice the result will show up and i will need to press enter to 1. clear the terminal then show the menu again.

Comment: So move the `clear` inside `themenu()` function?

Comment: You could also use `select` instead of building its functionality yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps something like this:

```
.
.
.
  esac

  echo ""      
  echo "Press <ENTER> to return to the menu..."
  read junk
  clear
done
```